# Show that the open rectangle (a,b) x (c,d) is an open set for any metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> *Question*: Let $A$ denotes the rectangle $(a, b)\times(c,d)$, and let
> $d\colon \mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that
> $(\mathbb R^2,  d)$ is a metric space. How do I show that $A$ is open
> in the metric space $(\mathbb R^2, d)$?

My approach is to use the definition of an open set: for all $(x,y)$ in $A$ there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x,y)$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: what did the problem actually ask? I know it wasn't just _any_ metric...

Comment: The question reads: '' show that an 'open rectangle' (a,b)x(c,d) is an open set in R2.'' the metric( distance) is not defined.

Comment: so you just made up the part about "for any metric" to make it harder???

Comment: how would you answer this question if you skipped over the metric part?

Comment: the problem of an undefined metric is that I can't use the Euclidian distance, meaning that most other proofs for this problem don't suffice. That's why I added the any metric part.

Comment: If the problem asked just to show that that rectangle was an open set then they intended to talk about the _standard_ metric $d(x,y)^2=(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2$.

Comment: It should seem very unlikely to be true.  We should be able to conceive of a metric where huge numbers are always close to to a point on the edge.  It might take a bit of kicking to get the details (see David Ullrich's answer) but one can.

Answer (score 3):

In comments it appears that the original question did not say anything about what metric was intended, hence the OP added the bit about "any metric".

In fact of course the *standard* Euclidean metric is the default here. How to show that rectangle is open in the standard metric is the sort of question we're not supposed to answer, so I won't. But someone should point out for the benefit of the OP that the assertion is *false* with "any" metric.

For example, define $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
(3,0),&(x=(0,0)),
\\(0,0),&(x=(3,0)),
\\x,&(x\ne(3,0),(0,0))\end{cases},$$let $d_E$ be the standard metric and define $$d(x,y)=d_E(f(x),f(y)).$$Since $d_E$ is a metric and $f$ is a bijection it follows easily that $d$ is a metric. But $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$ is not open, because if $r>0$ then $$(3+r/2,0)\in B((0,0),r),$$so $B((0,0),r)\not\subset(-1,1)^2$.